# Elasticsearch spark, how to update timestamp

Tags: python, apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark

how to update `date` field with elasticsearch spark.

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
t = int(datetime.datetime.timestamp(now))
# t = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()
params = f"key:<test3>,timestamp:<{t}>"

esconf["es.update.script.params"] = params
```

you will get error like

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException:
Invalid param definition timestamp:2020-01-03T14:46:51
```

I have tried using `timestamp (epoch)` and `isoformat` and hoped for ES to detect it and insert it as `date` field, but it's recognized either as long or string.

from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html#cfg-multi-writes

> es.update.script.params (default none) Script parameters (if any). The
>   document (currently read) field/property who’s value is used. To
>   specify a constant, use the `<CONSTANT>` format. Multiple values can be
>   specified through commas (,)

Comment: It doesn't look like the angle brackets are being used

Comment: I added the doc to op where it says the bracket